# Issues on CANbus on debian platform

Tags: debian, can-bus

I have an issue when using CAN communication on a Debian microcontroller. It has two CAN: CAN1 and CAN2. I tried to check using can-utils, I have connected both can bus together and then set can2 to listen using `candump can2`
and then sent data from CAN1 using `cansend can1 1F334455#1122334455667788`. I have received nothing. The other way around gave the same issue.
Then I used `ip -det link show can1`the results showed that CAN1 and Can2 states are ERROR-ACTIVE:

```
 can1: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
link/can  promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0
can state ERROR-ACTIVE (berr-counter tx 0 rx 0) restart-ms 0
      bitrate 38400 sample-point 0.800
      tq 5208 prop-seg 1 phase-seg1 2 phase-seg2 1 sjw 1
      c_can: tseg1 2..16 tseg2 1..8 sjw 1..4 brp 1..1024 brp-inc 1
      clock 24000000numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

I cannot seem to find the error

Comment: Not enough info to answer. Do you have a valid physical bus? [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)